# Open Power plan window using RunDll32.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, autohotkey, rundll32.exe

I am a power user of AutoHotKey. Currently, I want to create a shortcut to open Power plan in windows 7.

The window I want to open is in the screenshot below

[image]

I tried the following commands too but they seem to open different dialogs.

```
 rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL powercfg.cpl

 rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL powercfg.cpl,,1
```

So, How can I open this dialog box using run?

Comment: To want end do you want to display the box? Do you just want to see the battery life?

Comment: @MCL, As a shortcut to change power plan and see battery % of course

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to open? The "popup" in your screenshot or the control panel dialog for power plans? The way I see it, those are two different things.

Comment: @MCL popup that is in my screenshot

Comment: I suggest taking another approach: Windows exposes functions for both checking the battery status and changing power schemes. For battery life, check [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7022-acbattery-status/) out. For changing power schemes, you can use Windows' [powercfg.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940.aspx) via command line. Here's an [example](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/34589-how-to-change-power-schemes-via-hotkey/) in AHK. Now, you can build hotkeys for both of those functions, maybe spicing it up with your own GUI or a TrayTip.

Comment: But frankly, what is the problem with just clicking the tray icon?

Comment: @MCL Actually, I am power user of keyboard shortcuts. I have created shortcuts and use them for commonly used tasks like open browser, connect internet, skype,...That's why I want to create shortcut to check batter status and change mode

Answer (score 0):

Press Win+X or run `%SystemRoot%\System32\mblctr.exe`for [Windows Mobility Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-mobility-center#1TC=windows-7).

[image]

> If you use a laptop, you can quickly access settings (for example,
>   speaker volume, wireless network connection status, and display
>   brightness) in Windows Mobility Center.

Comment: Sorry but I want the dialog as shown in my screenshot